# Как правильно организовать данные для отображения в сетке? JS

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Изучаю создание сеток в JS

Сетка в два блока ширины и до бесконечности вниз.
Есть импромизированный ответ с сервера - массив объектов.

Вот один из них.

```
 {

      text: '123123123',
      size: 'half',
      type: 'house',
      id: 2  
    },
```

Если будет не четное количество таких блоков, а за ними тот что занимает всю ширину, то появляется пустое место.

Есть другой масив объектов, с блоками выполняющими другой функционал, но такого же размера. Нужно понять, как их вставить в нужное место.

[image: Синий - это я уже вставил необходимы блок в необходимое место]

Но с учетом что много вариантов, я не могу это сделать массово, для всей сетки, и чать областей остаются пустыми.

Вот моя реализация
fullItemList - масив блоков
smallItemList - масив блоков для пустых мест ([0] пока не имеет значения)

```
fullItemList.map((item, index) => {
if( (index +2) <= fullItemList.length && (index -2) <= fullItemList.length ) {
                if(
                    item.size === 'half'
                    && fullItemList[index-1 ].size  === 'Full'
                    && fullItemList[index+1 ].size  !== 'half'

                ) {
                    newArrf.splice(index+1,0, this.state.smallItemList[0])

                }
            }


        }
```

Comment: Опишите структуру данных на этом примере, которую надо получить.

Comment: Да, я недостаточно точно задал вопрос.


Сейчас изучаю сетки контента. Решил написать свою, для максимального понимания.

Сетка у меня на два дива в ширину(size: full)
В высоту до бесконечности.
Есть массив "статей" , часть из них занимает все два блока в ширину(size: full).


Когда между двумя блоками full , не четное количество стандартных блоков.

То появляется пустое место. Его я и хочу заполнить блоками из другого масива.
с подключениями и т д уже разобрался. Осталось научиться встраивать блок в нужное место.

Comment: А применительно к этой задаче? Как выглядят необходимые данные в виде элементов языка?

Comment: @NaviCross Для вставки блоков есть множество возможностей. Всё зависит от Вашей разметки `hmtl` и чёткого понимания, какого результата Вы хотите добиться.

Comment: Теперь наши ответы здесь вообще ни к селу. Возвращайте все в зад, закрывайте вопрос лучшим ответом и оформляйте другой вопрос. Только детально данные с сервера, как распознать там двойные блоки, дополнительный список как выглядит и все такое. Думаю, можно без картинок и так все понятно. Это мое мнение, конечно.

Comment: Почему сразу не оперировать всеми блоками, поделить их на два массива: половинчатые и полные, вычислить соотношение, рисунок повторяющийся относительно размера. Например `4*1/2 + 1*1 + 2*1/2 + 1*1`.  Потом согласно схеме распределять элементы на странице.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В качестве ключа объект со строкой и индексом, в качестве значения повторы:

```js
let arr = ['**дерево**','куст','куст','**дерево**','трава','**дерево**'];

let result = [];
let counter = 0;

arr.forEach((s,i, ar) => {
  if(s !== '**дерево**' && ar[i+1] === '**дерево**'){
    result.push({'beforeTree': s, 'index': i, 'num': counter});
    counter = 0;
  } else {
    counter++;
  }
})

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Я теперь понял для чего массив))

Comment: ))) Ну да, но проще всё в один объект сразу запихнуть.

Comment: Я по-другому сделал, сразу все в массив разместил)

Comment: Так Вы в массив объекты поместили ))) Добавьте `console.log(typeof {'beforeTree': s, 'index': i, 'num': counter});` А я к тому, что можно в один объект всё поместить. Зачем добавлять в массив несколько объектов.

Comment: Я так и хотел, массив объектов, каждый говорит кто он, на каком месте стоит и сколько было до него включительно))

Comment: Ну тогда да ))) Правда наши с Вами ответы теперь ни к чему как я понял )

Answer (score 6):

`key` - это ключ перед словом `**дерево**`
Значение - это количество.

```js
    let val = ['**дерево**','куст','куст','**дерево**','трава','**дерево**'];

    let temp = new Object(); // Создаём объект, чтобы был и ключ и значение
    let count = 0; // счётчик
    let result = []; // Массив результата
    for(let i=0;i<val.length;i++){ // Перебираем
        if(val[i] != '**дерево**'){ // Если значение НЕ равно **дерево**, то...
            count += 1; // Прибавляем к счётчику единицу
        } else {
            
            if(i>0) { // Если ключ больше 0
                let iz = i - 1; // Получаем предыдущий ключ.
                temp['key'+iz] = count; // Добавляем в объект значение key и ключ перед словом, и значение по количеству элементов между
                count = 0; // Сбрасываем счётчик
            }
        }
    }
    result.push(temp); // Добавляем в объект в массив
    console.log(result); // Выводим в консоль
```

Comment: Почему массив объектов? В каком случае появится второй объект? Индекс каждого элемента перед деревом ведь будет уникальным, может и хранить его в качестве ключа?

Comment: @Leonid В массиве всего один объект. Если Вы будете именно в массив добавлять ключ, то если у Вас, например, ключи получатся 3, 5. То массив будет примерно такой `[empy,empty,empty,2,empty,1]`. А в объекте можно сохранить только нужные вещи. Второго объекта не появится ))) Можно работать и как с объектом. Просто для вывода.

Comment: Я к тому, что структура могла быть: `{ "2" : 2, "4" : 1 }`, а сейчас она `[{"key2" : 2, "key4" : 1}]` )))

Comment: @Leonid Но это всё равно объект будет. А так да, можно хранить и так. Но тогда ничего непонятно будет.  Я наоборот специально ключ добавил, чтобы было понимание что и куда пишется.

Comment: Лишь бы автору было понятно, как извлечь индекс из "key2" ).

Comment: Да, я наверно в корне вопрос не так задал.   Возможно изначально структуру входных данных нужно выставить по другому.    Сейчас перефразирую вопрос

Answer (score 1):

не ясно с какой целью вам там индекс перед деревом, и главное, перед каким именно в паре, а также, что с эти делать, если между парой ничего нет. но вот пример с индексами обоих деревьев в паре и числом всякой всячины перед ними.

```js
const data = ['qwe','**дерево**','куст','куст','**дерево**','трава','**дерево**'];


let res = data.reduce(function(acc, v, idx){
           if(v != '**дерево**') return acc;
           
           if(acc.lastIdx != undefined){
             acc.data.push({
                  s: acc.lastIdx,
                  e: idx,
                  q: idx - acc.lastIdx - 1
                });
           }
           acc.lastIdx = idx;  
              
           return acc;           
       }, { lastIdx: undefined, data: [] }).data;
       
console.log(res);
```